# Почему может блокироваться доступ по SFTP в filezilla?

Tags: ssh, файловая-система, putty, sftp

На стороне клиента с недавних пор прекратился доступ по SFTP в FileZilla. В качестве ошибки сообщает: "Connection timed out".

При этом также прекратился доступ по SSH в PuTTY. Ошибка та же. Это точно на стороне клиента, так как с другой машины подключается успешно. 
Антивирус Avast, но он стоял и тогда, когда был доступ.
Брандмауэр windows отключен.

Comment: Я бы не был столь категоричным, что это точно на клиенте. Во первых сервер может блокировать входящие соединения по ip подключающегося. Во вторых порт может быть заблокирован по каким -то причинам где то на маршруте до целевого сервера

Comment: Первое точно нет. Как можно проверить второе?

Comment: У вас есть какой нибудь еще сервер куда можно попробовать подключиться ? Вряд ли блокировка, если она где то близко к вам, действует только на конкретные сервера, она должна блокировать 22 порт куда угодно. В идеале конечно было бы на целевом сервере убедится, что запросы вообще не доходят, но для этого нужен рут на той системе. Кстати, откуда уверенность, что целевой сервер не блокирует ?

Comment: Обращался к их поддержке, они разобрались. К любому серверу по 22 закрыто.

Comment: Скачал VPN, с помощью VPN подключается! Что это может значить? Провайдер шалит?

Comment: Ну ты же сказал, что пров ответил что 22 закрыт или он его открыл в итоге ?

Comment: Если подключаться через VPN, подключение есть. Если через основной IP-адрес моего провайдера - подключения нет.

Comment: Ну это точно к провайдеру. Значит они для ip которые выдают для vpn доступ не блокируют, а для остальных блокируют. не понимаю правда с чего они это делают, но у каждого свои тараканы :)

Answer (score 1):

возможно, где-то по пути пакеты блокируются на основании номера порта.

попробуйте на сервере в программе, реализующей протокол *ssh*, указать ещё один порт для входящих соединений и укажите этот порт в клиентской программе.

если слушает программа в реализации *openssh*, то в файле `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` можно указать несколько портов примерно так:

```
port 22
port 12345
...
```

программу после внесения изменений, конечно, надо перезагрузить.

Comment: Скачал VPN, с помощью VPN подключается! Что это может значить? Провайдер шалит?